# Give admin access to Standard Platform User

Tags: apex, visualforce, case

I am trying to use `web-to-case`. I have a vf page and controller for this. I am able to create a `case` when I am logged in as system administrator.

I have another user with user license as *Salesforce Platform* and Profile as *Standard Platform User*. When I log in with this user and use the link of the `vf page`, I get an error message saying **Insufficient Privileges**. I tried using

```
   public with sharing class sharingClass{

     // my_code here
}
```

But still the permission did not change. How can I give access this profile ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: take a look at this post : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/62709/error-insufficient-privileges-while-querying-user-or-userrole-in-a-standard-use/62712#62712

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access Cases functionality with just a platform license. You need Sales Cloud or Service Cloud License. Check this, but I'm pretty sure this is the case.

Comment: So how am I able to access case with system admin ? I don't have Sales Cloud or Service Cloud License either.

Comment: Which type of org are you in? Dev org with 2 full licenses (basically sales and service cloud) with 5 platform licenses

Comment: the thing which I am trying in is a free user. however my organisation has license. But I am testing on free user because we want to give access who do not have license.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've tried adding page access to the profile, no?
[image]

Comment: This is a valid answer, but perhaps include how to do this as well as the screenshot.